# Facing Auto Merge failure after teammate amends his changes

Tags: git

I'm facing an issue while working with git.

**Scenario:**

Me and my teammate is working on a code. Say it has 2 files.

```
File-1
File-2
```

Suppose on Day 1 we both have code at same level, say `Commit-0`.

On day 2, my team mate pushed some changes in File-1. This is `commit-1`.

On day 3, I want to make some changes in File-2, but before that I take a pull to get latest changes. So my code is now at `commit-1`.

I'm in process of making some changes in File-2 and have not pushed them yet.

On day 3 only, my team mate makes some more changes in File-1, but instead of pushing them as new commit, he uses `amend` & edits his original `commit-1`, say the new commit is now `commit-1.1`

On day 4, now I want to push my changes in File-2. But just to be sure that there are no conflicts, I stash my changes and then run `git pull`.

As soon I do this, I'm getting Auto merge fail in File-1.

For me it is difficult to do manual merge as I don't have idea what is being done in File-1.

For now I'm exporting my stash in a `.patch`. Then take a fresh checkout of latest code and then apply patch changes, which is a very bad solution.

Please suggest what should I do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset your local branch to the remote state to start again from your coworker's last amended commit, and apply your stash on that. (Might as well backup your local branch first.)

```
git branch backup_local
git reset --hard @{upstream}
git stash apply
```

Then resolve conflicts if any.